# Change the zoom out view in compiz

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, virtual-desktop, compiz

When I zoom out to see all my virtual desktops using the expo plugin in compiz, it displays them side by side. I want to make the windows bigger. I have four virtual desktops and would prefer to have it display two in one row and two in another row so that I can get a better view of what's going on in them. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you modify the workspace settings? Right-click on Gnome's own virtual desktop switcher, choose Preferences, make that contain 2 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: That fixed it for one of my monitors, but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by increasing/decreasing the distance in the compiz config settings.
Open up ccsm (Compiz Config Settings Manager) and open up the settings for the **Expo** plugin.
There under the **Appearance** tab there's a slider for **Distance**, you can change that to make the windows bigger or smaller. I haven't tried it, but I think if you make the windows bigger in size, they will automatically get displayed in 2 rows.

Comment: The distance is already at 0. Increasing it just makes everything smaller.